# Access constant in HTML in Ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic-framework, constants, ionic3

My project is in Ionic 3. I have a data provider class for storing constants.

ex

```
export const CONST1 = 1; 
export const CONST2 = 2;

@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

In my Display Page, I want to use the constant data. So If I do

```
import * as Data from './../../providers/data/data';
```

I can directly access `Data.CONST1` in my Display.TS file.
How do access the values in my Display.HTML file? There `Data.CONST1` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be by assigning the `Data` object to a public property of that component:

```
import * as Data from './../../providers/data/data';

// ...

@Component({
    selector: 'page-display,
    templateUrl: 'display.html'
})
export class DisplayPage {

    public constants = Data;

    // ...

}
```

And then in the view

```
<p>{{ constants.CONST1 }}</p>
```

**EDIT:**

> I want to use it as an input parameter and `<ion-input
>   maxLength="constants.CONST1"></ion-input>` does not work.

That's actually because you need to use attribute binding, to let angular know that the expression between "" must be interpreted:

```
<ion-input [attr.maxLength]="constants.CONST1"></ion-input>
```

Comment: I want to use it as an input parameter and <ion-input maxLength="constants.CONST1"></ion-input> does not work. Sorry this was not clear in the question.

Comment: Np, I've edited the answer, please let me know if that works :)

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @TapasMukherjee :)